# Before-insert trigger gets 'too many rows' error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a trigger:

```
create or replace trigger trig
  before insert on sistem  
  for each row
declare
  v_orta number;
 begin
   SELECT v_orta INTO :new.orta_qiymet
   FROM   sistem;
   v_orta:=(:new.riyaziyyat+:new.fizika)/2;

   insert into sistem(orta_qiymet)
   values(v_orta);

end trig;
```

When I insert a row:

```
insert into sistem(riyaziyyat,fizika) values(4,4)
```

I get an error:

[image: error capture]

Why am I getting that error?

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't copy the error into the question as text? Unless `sistem` only has one row - which is only true for your second insert - that select will always error. You're also asking for a mutating table error. Why are you selecting at all? You don't use the selected `v_orta` anyway. And why are you inserting into the same table again? That will cause an infinite loop... Maybe you can explain what you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fundamentally not understanding how triggers work. You can't generally select from the table the trigger is against, and a before-insert trigger shouldn't not insert into the same table again - as that would just cause the trigger to fire again, infinitely (until Oracle notices and stops it). You aren't even currently using the `v_orta` value you're attempting to query.

I suspect you think the trigger is *instead of* your original insert perhaps, and really you want to set the `orta_qiymet` value in the newly-inserted row automatically based on the other two columns you have supplied. To do that you don't (and can't) select those values; instead you refer to [the `:NEW` pseudorecord](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955) as you are already doing, and then set the third column value in that same pseudorow:

```
create or replace trigger trig
  before insert on sistem  
  for each row
begin
  :new.orta_qiymet := (:new.riyaziyyat + :new.fizika)/2;
end trig;
/
```

There is a lot of information in the documentation; this is similar to [one of the examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#BCFDEHHE).